# Iridescent duck and photonics in nature. Why duck's head is only green?

Tags: optics, visible-light, maxwell-equations, biophysics, photonics

We all know and adore pure beauty of mallard male:

[image]

I know that such iridescent colours are usually a result of feathers forming a photonic crystal with layers of air sandwiched between layers of feathers. However as I know (e.g. from observing a layer of gasoline spilled on water), wavelength of the reflected light depends on the angle of the incidence:
[image]

(The lightwave reflected is a result of constructive interference of waves reflected by each interface. If the angle changes there are different optical paths for reflected waves and different wavelength will be stronger).

So why is duck's head only green and dark green/black? Why aren't there more colours to see, depending on the angle?

Comment: see color perception https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_vision

Comment: @annav humans can see not only green, perception is secondary here. Soap bubbles e.g. [aren't green](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Soap_bubble_sky.jpg).

Comment: @Ruslan  but you are talking of perception. Many different frequencies add up to green, and changing reflections if you see the plot will change the mixture of frequencies and give a different color perception http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vision/colper.html

Comment: @annav your link doesn't work for me. But anyway, I'm not talking about perception. My answer explains why there's no dependence of the peak of the spectral power distribution on the scattering angle that would be expected of an iridescent material. This is totally agnostic of human—or any other animal—color vision.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The color of the feathers' structural elements indeed depends on angle of incidence/scattering (and also on position in the feather). But the feather itself is made of a lot of very small elements. We see the whole system as an average of the varying colors of the elements, which are oriented differently.

See e.g. ref. 1 figure 2 (the bars here correspond to $100\,\mathrm{\mu m}$):

[image: Ref 1 Fig 2a,b]

These images (a) and (b) correspond, respectively, to asterisk and arrowhead in figure 1d (the bar here corresponds to $2\,\mathrm{cm}$):

[image: Ref 1 Fig 1d]

#### References

1. Stavenga DG, van der Kooi CJ, Wilts BD. 2017 Structural coloured feathers
   of mallards act by simple multilayer photonics. *J. R. Soc. Interface* **14**: 20170407. http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsif.2017.0407